# Trouble passing a struct to a thread function in C

Tags: c, multithreading, function

We are trying to add nodes to a linked list in one thread, and delete nodes from the linked list in the other thread.

We believe the following line is our problem: if(time(NULL) == llnode->time)
.We are trying to access the time in the head node of the list. I'm not sure if we are passing the correct arguments to the functions. The thread to create nodes is working correctly, but the thread to delete nodes isn't. It's resulting in a segmentation fault. It'd be greatly appreciated if anyone could point me in the right direction, as I've been stuck on this for a while.

```
/* Link list node */
struct node
{
    int roomNo;
    time_t time;
    struct node* next;
};

void * addThread(void *n) 
{  
   struct node *llnode = n;
   time_t date;
   int room;
   struct tm * timeptr;
   pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
   while (pending < 5)
   { 
       printf("Adding node.\n");
       insert(&llnode, getRandRoom(), getRandTime());
       date = getRandTime();
       room = getRandRoom();
       timeptr = localtime(&date);
       printf("Registered:   %d %s", room, asctime(timeptr));
       sleep(1);
       pending++;
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void * wakeThread(void *n) 
{   
   struct node *llnode = n;
   while(1)
   {    
        if(time(NULL) == llnode->time)
        { 
            printf("Deleting head node.\n");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            deleteNode(&llnode);
            pending--;
            expired++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node* head;
    head = NULL;
    signal(SIGINT, ctrlc_catch);

    pthread_t addWakeup, makeWakeup;

    pthread_create(&addWakeup, NULL, addThread, (void*)head);
    sleep(6);
    pthread_create(&makeWakeup, NULL, wakeThread, (void*)head);

    pthread_join(addWakeup, NULL);
    pthread_join(makeWakeup, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the prototypes for our functions that aren't shown in the code(functions have been tested outside the threads and are fully functional):

```
void insert(struct node** head_ref, int new_room, time_t new_time);
void deleteNode(struct node** head_ref);
```

Comment: It looks like once your list is empty, llnode in wakeThread() could possibly be NULL. Is that possible, given the rest of the code? If so, you can add a NULL check.

Comment: Besides aix's answer, which correctly points the problem, let me add that `time(NULL) == llnode->time` is very bad practice. It may never evaluate to true, for reasons that may vary depending on the native hardware, the clocking of the CPU, the utilization of the CPU, the daylight savings mode, and the current phase of the moon. Use `>=` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head` in `main()` is a pointer to `struct node`. It's initialized to `NULL` and passed to the thread functions. They both receive a `NULL` pointer. Then `addThread()` might be able to grow its own node list with `insert()`, but `wakeThread()` is definitely not going to delete any of it with `deleteNode()`, because it just doesn't have the right pointer, all it has is a NULL pointer, which it tries to dereference and crashes.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, `head` starts off as `NULL` and remains `NULL` for the lifetime of your program. The `NULL` pointer gets passed to `wakeThread`, which proceeds to dereference it (`llnode->time`). This is what triggers the segfault.

To fix, you need to make sure that any changes that the `addThread` makes to `head` are visible to  the `wakeThread`. One way to do it is by passing **a pointer** to `head` to both threads. If you do this, make sure you get the locking right!

Comment: I understand what you mean, but is there anyway you could show me an example please? I'm a bit of a C beginner.